# Which familiar-related abilities require the 1 mile proximity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, familiars

[Wizard familiar rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/classes/wizard.html#familiars) say:

> A familiar grants special abilities to its master, as given on the table below. These special abilities apply only when the master and familiar are within 1 mile of each other.

The "table below" happens to be the Special Ability table showing which skill bonuses you get per familiar type.

Does this mean your familiar going beyond 1 mile only removes that specific skill bonus? What about the other level-dependant *special abilities* such as Alertness, Empathic Link, etc...?

Also, quick side question: Ravens being able to speak one language is among the skill bonuses table. I suppose it means they cannot speak said language if they go beyond 1 mile of their master?

EDIT:
I just noticed Empathic Link specifically mentions it only goes up to 1 mile. Since it's the only ability where it's specified, I'm guessing it means it is not a usual limitation. If no one disagrees or posts an answer that goes in that sense, I'll post one myself sometime later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Only Familiar Abilities Granted to the Master

When the text says, "A familiar grants special abilities to its master, as given on the table below. These special abilities apply only when the master and familiar are within 1 mile of each other" (*Pathfinder Role-playing Game Core Rulebook* 82), the phrase *these special abilities* refers to those abilities granted to the familiar's master by the table (usually a bonus to a skill check or saving throw) *not* to *all* abilities granted to the familiar as benefits of being a familiar. As the raven familiar doesn't grant his master the ability to speak 1 language, the raven retains its own ability to speak 1 language no matter its distance from its master.

To clarify, the master of a raven familiar loses the +3 bonus to Appraise checks when his raven familiar travels outside the 1 mile limit, but the raven wouldn't lose its ability to speak 1 language nor would it lose any abilities from the chart detailing Familiar Ability Descriptions (*Pathfinder Role-playing Game Core Rulebook* 82). Some of the latter abilities might not be *usable* because of the distance between raven and master, but the abilities aren't lost.